# NameError: name 'ask' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit

problem with flask ask

@ask.launch issue

am having problem running my python flask script. I am using python 2.7, the error says:
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\hello_lumion.py", line 13, in @ask.launch NameError: name 'ask' is not defined

```
import logging
import os 


from flask import request
from flask import Flask

from flask_ask import Ask, statement, request, context, session, question,  version

import requests


@ask.launch
def welcome():
    return statement ('Welcome to Foo')


app = Flask(__name__)

ask= Ask(app,"/")

logging.getLogger("flask_ask").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@ask.intent("Hello")

def hello():
    msg= "hello from lumion"
    return statement (msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 9000
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

any advice on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `Ask` instead of `ask`?  That's the only similar name that's actually defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: It  literally says that NameError: name 'ask' is not defined

do you have an idea on how to overcome this particular issue. I searched everywhere couldn't find someone who encountered similar issue to mine. according to flask documentation yes it needs to be written this way so it is 'ask' not ASK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ask` before it is defined. In your code you have

```
@ask.launch # ask has not been made
def welcome():
    return statement ('Welcome to Foo')


app = Flask(__name__)

ask= Ask(app,"/") # ask gets made here!
```

You will need to reorder it so when you call `ask`, it has been defined. Something like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

ask= Ask(app,"/") # define it first

@ask.launch # now use it
def welcome():
    return statement ('Welcome to Foo')
```